# Wikipedia API: articles rating

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

is there any wikipedia API to help in rate their topics, to find if it contain nude or sexual content or not, like movies ? (proper for kids or not)

I did alot of search, but can't find something like this

thanks,

Comment: What is it that you want to filter? ”Proper for kids” is highly subjective...

Comment: Also: What Wikipedia edition are you talking about? Categorisation and labeling of content is up to each community, so it will be very different.

Comment: I want to check if article proper for kids by article id @leo

Answer (score 2):

In general: No.

The concept of “proper for kids or not” is highly subjective, and will depend on culturally and personally held views.

However, some Wikipedia editions do have systems to label or categorize content that might be disturbing. These systems are normally guidelines, agreed on by the respective community. You will have to check the Wikipedia you are interested in using (you don't tell us what language you are interested in).

As an example, [Malay Wikipedia](https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laman_Utama) uses a template called [`{{18sx}}`](https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Templat:18sx) on sexually explicit content. Hence, you could sort out articles with that template. To check for that template in the article on masturbation, you would use `action=query&prop=templates` on the article [`Pelancapan`](https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelancapan):

```
https://ms.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Zakar_manusia&prop=templates
```

The answer, by the way, is “yes”.

On English Wikipedia, there is a consensus not to use such templates. For some of the reasons, see e.g.:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_disclaimers_in_articles
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Offensive_material

Related reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_Wikipedia
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Pornography
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Options_to_hide_an_image
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Restricted_materials

Comment: I'm focusing on English